# how to play a video like facebook from azure blob storage using node.js as backend and angularjs as front end

Tags: node.js, azure

I have a designed a social site similar to facebook using azure and nodejs.
while creating video posts I want to play them like videos playing in facebook,
while the videos are stored in azure blob storage.

Comment: check out azure media services https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/media-services/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage [Microsoft Azure Storage SDK for Node.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node#microsoft-azure-storage-sdk-for-nodejs) to generate a SAS token URL of your video blobs for your clients to play.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
function getSharedAccessPolicy(accessTimeInMinutes) {
    var startDate = new Date();
    var expiryDate = new Date(startDate);
    expiryDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() + accessTimeInMinutes);
    startDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() - accessTimeInMinutes);

    var sharedAccessPolicy = {
        AccessPolicy: {
            Permissions: azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.READ,
            Start: startDate,
            Expiry: expiryDate
        },
    };
    return sharedAccessPolicy;
}

function getWriteSAS() {
    var blobService = azure.createBlobService('<account_name>','<account_key>');
    var container = '<container>';
    var blobName = '<video-blob>';
    var blobSAS = blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature(container, blobName, getSharedAccessPolicy(10));
    var sharedBlobService = azure.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobService.host, blobSAS);
    return blobService.getUrl(container,blobName,blobSAS)
}
console.log(getWriteSAS());
```

Then you can set in the `video` tag in client html script, e.g.

```
<video width="100%" controls >
    <source src="<SAS token URL>" />
</video>
```